# How to calculate time duration in days (potential undefined values) in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object array and each object has: `startDate` and `endDate`. Both `startDate` and `endDate`  are `string` or `undefined value`. I would like to think of a function that can calculate the duration in days between `startDate` and `endDate`. (If either of dates is undefined, I would like to get 0 as duration instead)

Simple example data:

```
const USER = [
{
  name: "user1",
  startDate: "2020-01-01",
  endDate: "2021-01-01"
},
{
  name: "user2",
  startDate: "",
  endDate: "2021-01-01"
},
{
  name: "user3",
  startDate: "2020-01-01",
  endDate: undefined
}
]
```

So far, I have tried:

```
function getDuration(user) {
    const startDate = (typeof user.startDate !== "undefined") ? new Date(user.startDate) : 0;
    const endDate = (typeof user.endDate !== "undefined") ? new Date(user.endDate) : 0;
    return endDate - startDate; ***
  }

USER.map(user => getDuration(user))
```

I got similar error on both `startDate` and `endDate` in the *** line:

```
The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2363)
const startDate: Date | 0
```

I am still learning typescript. Can anyone help me on how to get time duration in typescript if the value contain `undefined`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `startDate` and `endDate` a `Date` instead of a number

You need to use `.getTime()` on the date (in order to get the time in milliseconds)

```
function getDuration(user) {
    const startDate = (typeof user.startDate !== "undefined") ? new Date(user.startDate).getTime() : 0;
    const endDate = (typeof user.endDate !== "undefined") ? new Date(user.endDate).getTime() : 0;
    return endDate - startDate;
  }

USER.map(user => getDuration(user))
```

Comment: Thank you Raz. It can resolve the error. I have a naive question: How would you get duration in days?

Comment: Just divide it by 86,400,000 milliseconds